# material-ui snackbar change colorwith no making a new onefor each color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

how do i change the color of a snackbar without having to make a new one in material-ui do i have to create a new one for every color? In the example sandbox they have only one color the other ones are static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create different components, all you have to do is use hooks to pass properties to modify the component

```
 <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
    <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity={severity}>
    {message}
    </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
```

Like that you can pass the message you want and the severity you want in one component
here is a working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-frost-itv99

Edit:

As Dekel pointed out the `<Alert>` is a different component and it is the one reciving the severity and message.

Answer (score 1):

The `snackbar` doesn't have specific color settings, but the content of the snackbar can be anything you want.

For example - you can put the `<Alert>` component inside the snackbar, and materia's alert component has multiple values for `severity` which controls the color of the alert.

This will generate a green alert:

```
<Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
  <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success">
    This is a success message!
  </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

This will generate a red alert:

```
<Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
  <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="error">
    This is a success message!
  </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

The green and the red are coming from the [`<Alert>` component](https://material-ui.com/es/components/alert/).